# Why is this function causing the browser refresh button to grey out?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am testing a real time graph with chart js, and wrote the simple code below. Every second, I want to redraw the graph with some new data (shift and push in the datas and labels array). Despite how ugly it is, it works, and updates the graph every second. However, the refresh button greys out (for some milliseconds) every time the function executes, even if there is no interaction with the network. Why?

```
setInterval(function() {
    var ctx = document.getElementById("line-chart-1").getContext("2d");
    var chart1 = window.chart1;

    var d1 = chart1.data.datasets[0].data;
    var lab1 = chart1.data.labels;

    var newData = dataPointGenerator(70, 80);

    d1.shift();
    d1.push(newData.data);

    lab1.shift();
    lab1.push(newData.time);

    window.chart1 = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels : lab1,
            datasets : [
                {
                    label: 'names[0]',
                    fill: false,
                    borderColor: "rgb(75,192,192)",
                    borderCapStyle: 'butt',
                    borderDash: [],
                    borderDashOffset: 0.0,
                    borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
                    pointBorderColor: "rgb(75,192,192)",
                    pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
                    pointBorderWidth: 1,
                    pointHoverRadius: 5,
                    pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgb(75,192,192)",
                    pointHoverBorderColor: "rgb(75,192,192)",
                    pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
                    pointRadius: 1,
                    pointHitRadius: 10,
                    data : d1
            }
        ]
    },
    options: {
        animation : false,
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: 'kW'
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});

function dataPointGenerator(start, end) {
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (end - start + 1) + start);
    var date = new Date();
    return {
        data : rand,
        time : date
    }
};
```

Comment: I don't think this is what's causing your page to go into a loading state.  How are you loading the data that populates this chart?

Comment: i dont think so... i edited the question to show how i am adding the data.

Comment: Can you open your browser's debugging tools and see if there are any pending network requests?  See how to open them here: [Chrome Network Panel](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/?hl=en#network).  If you have FireFox, you can also check in their dev tools.

Comment: i checked the chrome dev tools, and there don't seem to be any network requests. Could it be about rendering?